# image segmentation using kmeans clustering python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, k-means, opencv3.0, image-segmentation

I've been trying to achieve similar results to this [MATLAB code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html) 
 which gives me the result I am looking for, however, I am trying to achieve that using OpenCV 3 + Python.

Here's a similar implementation in OpenCV 3 + Python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

class Segment:
    def __init__(self,segments=5):
        #define number of segments, with default 5
        self.segments=segments

    def kmeans(self,image):
        image=cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(7,7),0)
        vectorized=image.reshape(-1,3)
        vectorized=np.float32(vectorized) 
        criteria=(cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
        ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(vectorized,self.segments,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
        res = center[label.flatten()]
        segmented_image = res.reshape((image.shape))
        return label.reshape((image.shape[0],image.shape[1])),segmented_image.astype(np.uint8)


    def extractComponent(self,image,label_image,label):
        component=np.zeros(image.shape,np.uint8)
        component[label_image==label]=image[label_image==label]
        return component

if __name__=="__main__":
    import argparse
    import sys
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
    ap.add_argument("-n", "--segments", required = False, type = int,
        help = "# of clusters")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    image=cv2.imread(args["image"])
    if len(sys.argv)==3:

        seg = Segment()
        label,result= seg.kmeans(image)
    else:
        seg=Segment(args["segments"])
        label,result=seg.kmeans(image)
    cv2.imshow("segmented",result)
    result=seg.extractComponent(image,label,2)
    cv2.imshow("extracted",result)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

What I'm looking for is being able to extract A by itself and rectangle around it by itself and the background by itself so I can manipulate them seperately.

Here you can see the original image + current output + desired output:

[image]

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I can't do this right now, but there are some differences between your implementation and Matlab's one that you should review:

- **Color space**: Matlab's example works on L*a*b* and your implementation on BGR, specifically on 'a*' and 'b*' channels
- **nClusters**: as you are not hard-coding it, I'm assuming you are using `segments=3` just like Matlab's examples does, right? Your default is 5...
- **GaussianBlur**: I can't see any blur being applied on Matlab's example
- **Attempts**: you are using `attempts=10`, while Matlab is only 3